# Is it correct to represent a foreign key on a conceptual data model?

Tags: database-design

Is it correct to represent a foreign key on a conceptual data model, or should I only introduce foreign keys when I am doing the relational model?

Comment: What do you mean by "conceptual"?  The term could have several different meanings.

Answer (score 7):

Experts are divided on this one.  Here's my opinion.

The classic ER (Entity-Relationship) model identifies relationships, but does not implement them as foreign keys.  In an ER diagram, relationships appear as lines between boxes.  Extra marks classify them as many-many or many-one, and as mandatory or optional.   A relational model always uses foreign keys to identify and implement relationships.  A relational model diagram will use lines between boxes for visual purposes, but a complete attribute list will include these foreign keys.

Another difference between ER modeling and relational modeling is that in relational modeling, a many-many relationship will be diagrammed as a box with two (or more) lines leading up to it.  In ER modeling, a binary many-many relationship is modeled without a box of its own.

I always used to construct the conceptual model using ER modeling, and leave the foreign keys out.  Then, at logical design time,  I would switch over to the relational model and plug in the foreign keys.  At this time, many-many relationships would acquire extra boxes of their own, to  hold a pair (or a tuple) of foreign keys.

Many experts don't follow my practice.  They opine that the ER model is superfluous for conceptual modeling, and that it's best to begin with a relational model at the conceptual level, while you are still doing the requirements analysis.  Then you don't have to switch modeling conventions in mid stream.  From a theoretical point of view they are right.

Where the ER model has served me well is in explaining the model to unsophisticated clients.  Some of them have a quicker intuitive grasp of the ER model than of the relational model.

Comment: +1 I agree with Walter - conceptual model is not normally representing detailed design - this is what physical model is for. Conceptual model's goal is to describe general break down in objects and what are the relationships - the design of foreign key is not important or you would go right to physical model and skip conceptual model

Comment: Excellent comment.  You clarify the difference between analysis and design.  I was hinting at that, but you laid it out.

Comment: An additional point that I did not make.  An ER model is implementation neutral (sometimes called implementation agnostic).  This can be enormously useful when analyzing business processes independently of some project that has an established implementation environment.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a modified Chen ER Model (Conceptual) used with foreign keys NOT represented.

[Example Modified Chen ER Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8th3q.png)

However, in the next model, the logical model (relational schema), the foreign key would be represented.

[Modified Chen ER Model Converted to Relational Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wydaD.png)

Additional examples and that modeling technique can be found in the following textbook:

Jukic, N., Vrbsky, S., Nestorov, S. (2014). Database Systems: Introduction to Databases and Data Warehouses.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys are entirely (and exclusively) part of the relational model.

Object models don't rely on foreign keys; they have direct object references not based on keys.

Comment: The OP queried about the conceptual model, not an object model.

Comment: @mdma: What did the OP mean by "conceptual"?  Do you have a definition  that the OP would agree to?

Comment: I would say that the conceptual model is the simplest model that captures the essence of the problem.  An object model (or relational model) is in logical model territory. Here's a simple comparison of conceptual, logical and physical models. http://www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/data-modeling-levels.html